# effects plots with partial residuals: why is xlevels evaluated at 100 values?

Tags: r, plot, effects, interaction

The help for argument `xlevels` in function `Effect` from the [effects](https://cran.r-project.org/package=effects) CRAN package by John Fox and collaborators says:

```
(...) If partial residuals are
computed, then the focal predictor that is to appear on the
horizontal axis of an effect plot is evaluated at 100 equally
spaced values along its full range, and, by default, other
numeric predictors are evaluated at the quantiles specified
in the ‘quantiles’ argument, unless their values are given
explicitly in ‘xlevels’.
```

I do not understand : 
1) what is the relevance of `xlevels` when the focal predictors are pairs of continuous and discrete variables (I would have expected it not to be relevant); 
2) why a value of 100 for `xlevels` for pairs of continuous predictors when the number of conditioning plots is about 2 to 4 in most cases;
3) how `xlevels` affects the focal predictor on the abscissa (it seems it doesn't).

1) If the model contains only a continuous predictor and a factor, it seems that `xlevels` plays no role and the partial residuals are obtained by evaluating the predictor at its actual values (which is what I would expect); in this case it seems to me that the text above does not apply. The following code compares the `Effect` plot with partial residuals obtained "by hand"

```
     library(effects)
     library(ggplot2)

     x11()
     x11()

     set.seed(123)
     n <- 6  ## with small n it is easier to compare the plots
     x1 <- rnorm(n, mean = 15)
     xf <- rep(c(0, 1), c(n/2, n - n/2))
     dd <- data.frame(y = x1 + x1 * 4 * xf + rnorm(n, 0, sd = 0.2),
                     x1 = x1, xf = factor(xf))
     mi1 <- lm(y ~ x1 * xf, data = dd)


     plot(Effect(c("x1", "xf"), mi1, partial.residuals = TRUE), nrow = 1)

     plot(Effect(c("x1", "xf"), mi1, partial.residuals = TRUE,
            xlevels = list(x1 = c(1, 9, 37)))) 

     ############# "By hand", step by step
     r1 <- resid(mi1)
     ## Individual beta_j * x_j terms to add
     add_x1 <- x1 * coefficients(mi1)["x1"]
     add_x1_f1 <- model.matrix(mi1)[, "x1:xf1"] * coefficients(mi1)["x1:xf1"]

     ## Partial residuals
     partial_residuals <- r1 + add_x1 + add_x1_f1

     ## For convenience for ggplot2
     pd <- data.frame(x1 = dd$x1, xf = dd$xf,
                    partial_residuals = partial_residuals,
                   fitted = fitted(mi1))

     dev.set(dev.next())
     ## Identical to the Effect plot.
     ggplot(data = pd, aes(x = x1, y = partial_residuals)) +
           geom_smooth(method = "lm") + geom_point() +
           facet_wrap( ~ xf, nrow = 1)
```

2 and 3). If the model contains two continuous predictors, I think that by modifying `xlevels` we can change the number of panels but I do not understand why the default is to evaluate at 100 values. If I understand correctly, what is being implemented here is an idea that John Fox and Sanford Weisberg discussed in, for example, [Visualizing Lack of Fit in Complex Regression Models: Adding Partial Residuals to Effect Displays](http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Courses/sem-goettingen/partial-residuals-effect-displays-notes-revised.pdf). On slide 34, for instance, we read "To obtain partial residuals, we round predictors in an effect, other than the focal predictor defining the horizontal axis, to sliced values." This I understand, but the slicing would not affect the focal predictor on the horizontal axis (only the focal predictor in the conditioning panels). The following code again compares with partial residuals obtained by "hand" by manually slicing only one of the predictors, and also shows that changing the `xlevels` for the focal predictor on the horizontal axis seems to make no difference and what matters is the slicing of the other predictor:

```
     set.seed(123)
     n <- 12  ## with small n easier to see
     x1 <- rnorm(n, mean = 15)
     x2 <- rep(c(1, 2, 8, 9), length.out = n) ## Simpler if few values
     dd2 <- data.frame(y = x1 + 2 * x1 * x2 + rnorm(n),
                       x1 = x1, x2 = x2)
     mi12 <- lm(y ~ x1 * x2, data = dd2)
     summary(mi12)


     ## Residuals + Individual beta_j * x_j terms to add
     tt <- c("x1", "x1:x2")
     pr2 <- resid(mi12) + model.matrix(mi12)[, tt] %*% coefficients(mi12)[tt]

     ## Partial residuals with slicing of x2:
     ## Evaluate x2 only at 1 and 9; all values 1 and 2 are set to 1
     ## and all 8 and 9 are set to 9. I think this is similar to
     ## "fitted <- y[good][closest(trans(x.fit), x[good])]"
     ## in line 317 in plot-methods.R?

     x22 <- dd2$x2
     x22[x22 == 2] <- 1
     x22[x22 == 8] <- 9

     mm2 <- cbind(x1 = dd2$x1, "x1:x2" = dd2$x1 * x22)
     pr2b <- resid(mi12) + mm2 %*% coefficients(mi12)[tt]

     ## For convenience for ggplot2
     pd2 <- data.frame(x1 = dd2$x1,
                       x2 = dd2$x2,
                       x22 = x22,
                       pr2 = pr2,
                       pr2b = pr2b)


     plot(Effect(c("x1", "x2"), mi12, partial.residuals = TRUE))
     dev.set(dev.next())
     ggplot(data = pd2, aes(x = x1, y = pr2)) +
         geom_smooth(method = "lm") + geom_point() +
         facet_wrap( ~ factor(x2, levels = c(8, 9, 1, 2)), nrow = 2)


     ## Only at two values of x2
     plot(Effect(c("x1", "x2"), mi12, partial.residuals = TRUE,
                 xlevels = list(x2 = c(1, 9), x1 = 5)))
     dev.set(dev.next())
     ggplot(data = pd2, aes(x = x1, y = pr2b)) +
         geom_smooth(method = "lm") + geom_point() +
         facet_wrap( ~ factor(x22), nrow = 1)

     ## other values for x1 make no difference
     plot(Effect(c("x1", "x2"), mi12, partial.residuals = TRUE,
                     xlevels = list(x2 = c(1, 9), x1 = 1)))
```

As mentioned in the example above, looking at the code, around line 317 of file `plot-methods.R`, (function `plot.eff`) we see `fitted <- y[good][closest(trans(x.fit), x[good])]`. Changing `xlevels` has no effect on the size of `x` in example 1), and only makes a difference in example 2-3) when we change the `xlevels` for `x2`; this seems coherent with the idea of "set the predictor in the conditioning panels to a set of sliced values if it is continuous ---unneeded with discrete predictors".

Answer (score 0):

John Fox provided the answer:

When a numeric predictor is “sliced,” this is done at a
relatively small number of values since each slice corresponds to
a panel in the display.  Using 100 values for a numeric predictor
that’s not sliced — that is, the predictor appearing on the
horizontal axis of the graph — allows us to compute fitted values
at a relatively small number of points, and then to use the
closest one, which speeds the computation.